# Add button horizontally to Page Control

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I need to add a button horizontally to a Page Control in UIPageViewController. I have added my pageviewcontroller as a subview to a ViewController, by default im getting the page control .Now I wanted to add a button, Can anyone suggest any way to add button ?

Thanks in advance!!

```
_pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
                                                          navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                                                        options:nil];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                @"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *p1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];
    UIViewController *p2 = [storyboard
                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
    UIViewController *p3 = [storyboard
                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Third"];
    UIViewController *p4 = [storyboard
                            instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Fourth"];
    _Array = @[p1,p2,p3,p4];
    _pageViewController.dataSource = self;
    _pageViewController.delegate = self;
    [_pageViewController setViewControllers:@[_Array[0]]
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:nil];

    [_pageViewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.pageViewController.view];    
    [_pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: show what you have tried so far ..

Comment: In the same line as page control I want a button to be used.

Comment: you can use `collectionView` instead, `pageViewController` made to add VC actually ..

Comment: I have to do it using pageviewcontroller

Comment: [i think you are looking for this kind of functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866407/horizontal-scrollview-having-n-number-of-buttons-ios) have a look.

Comment: sorry, I don' t think this will help my code

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what youre looking for. He explains in detail how to add the buttons "on top of " your page view controller view. You can do this after you add the page view controller, you can use the sendSubviewToBack method to ensure that the buttons remain in the foreground while you will be able to swipe between the different view controllers of your page view controller. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27583988/4433426)

Comment: Sorry i couldn't see the button when i tried your code

Comment: Did you send the page view controller to the back?

Comment: [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.pageViewController.view];
yes but couldn't view button

Comment: How are you adding the button and the pageview controller?

Comment: in the parent view controller not the pageviewcontroller. Also I believe that in the above example he is adding the pageviewcontroller programmatically

Comment: @HarmVanRisk i think this is not the solution for meowsush is actually looking for but at least idea about `pageViewController` , +1 for right explanation.

Comment: UIButton is added using the interface builder.

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry I couldn't be more help

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply

Comment: Just out of interest when you tap on Debug View Hierarchy is the button there at all?

Comment: sorry im new to iOS. can you tell me how to check ?

Comment: Thats ok we all start somewhere :) Have a look at this https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6

Comment: I have only that button in that viewcontroller  because everything i have i did    is on uipageviewcontroller and added it to he viewcontroller

Comment: But is the button in the view hierarchy?

Comment: yup , Its there

Comment: Can you update above with a screenshot of it's location?

Comment: sorry couldn't upload images because of low reputation

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the view where page control is kept on, then you can do what ever you want. Below is the code for extracing the pagecontrol view:

NSArray *subviews = self.pageController.view.subviews;

```
for (int i=0; i<[subviews count]; i++) {
    if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIPageControl class]]) {
        self.pageControl = (UIPageControl *)[subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    }
}
UIView *pageControlBaseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,60,100, 40)];
[pageControlBaseView addSubview:self.pageControl];
self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor redcolor];
self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor greencolor];
[self.view addSubview:pageControlBaseView];
```

please let me know if you need more clarity.